# Confusing group by syntax in oracle, how and why is this working?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wanted to group by on a nested select query result. I can't understand how and why this query even runs fine.. Is this the correct way to use a group by on a nested select column? We are on Oracle 11g.

```
select min(updated_at), max(updated_at), (select count(*) from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561 and domain_cdc_status = 'DONE') as done
from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561
group  by '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question as it looks very much like it shouldn't work at first glance, but then like it should work without the `group by` when you dig a bit deeper. It looks like a bug, or at least an inconsistency, in the parser.

The nested select isn't correlated so it only needs to be executed once, making its result effectively a constant, and the [documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm):

> In a query containing a GROUP BY clause, the elements of the select list can be aggregate functions, GROUP BY expressions, constants, or expressions involving one of these.

If you replaced it with the actual count value you wouldn't need the group by:

```
select min(updated_at), max(updated_at), 42 as done
from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561;
```

... which runs fine, and makes sense from what the docs said. The inconsistency is that with the nested select it will complain if you do this instead:

```
select min(updated_at), max(updated_at),
  (select count(*) from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561
    and domain_cdc_status = 'DONE') as done
from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561;

SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

but not if you include the redundant `group by null`. So from one perspective the parser doesn't know the nested select can be treated as a constant and expects a `group by` clause, but then it does know that expression doesn't need to actually be in the `group by`.

If the nested select was correlated then the `group by null` wouldn't work either:

```
select min(updated_at), max(updated_at),
  (select count(*) from domain_cdc dc2
    where dc2.app_context_id = dc1.app_context_id
    and domain_cdc_status = 'DONE') as done
from domain_cdc dc1
where app_context_id = 1561
group by null;

SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

So it's just a bit confused by your original query. Weird, but mostly harmless I think, and I realise that doesn't entirely answer the question... but it looks pretty similar to bug 18697654 if that's any help.

---

You don't need the nested select here though, you can use a case statement:

```
select min(updated_at), max(updated_at),
  count(case when domain_cdc_status = 'DONE' then updated_at end) as done
from domain_cdc where app_context_id = 1561;
```

`count` only counts not-null values; the case makes everything that isn't `'DONE'` null so they excluded from that aggregate. And since you now have no non-aggregate columns again, and the parse can understand what's happening, you don't need the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not a very big table, you can try something like:

```
SELECT distinct MAX (updated_at) OVER () AS max_updated_at,
       MIN (updated_at) OVER () AS min_updated_at,
       (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM domain_cdc
         WHERE domain_cdc_status = 'DONE')
          AS cnt_domain_cdc
  FROM domain_cdc
  where app_context_id = 1561
```

For for large table better solution (I believe) can look like:

```
SELECT max_updated_at, min_updated_at, cnt_domain_cdc
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS id, MAX (updated_at) AS max_updated_at, MIN (updated_at) AS min_updated_at
          FROM domain_cdc
         WHERE app_context_id = 1561) a
       JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id,
                    (SELECT COUNT (*)
                       FROM domain_cdc
                      WHERE domain_cdc_status = 'DONE' AND app_context_id = 1561)
                       AS cnt_domain_cdc
               FROM DUAL) b
          ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: that was not my question at all.